# TSQL Outer JOIN : Incorrect syntax near SELECT

Tags: sql, t-sql

Following TSQL script is throwing me an error "Incorrect syntax near SELECT". Please suggest.

```
    CREATE TABLE segments
    WITH(DISTRIBUTION =HASH(customer_key)) AS
    SELECT a.* 
    FROM t_segx a
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    SELECT b.*
    FROM t.segy b
    ON a.c_key = b.c_key
```

Comment: Afaik sql server doesn't support `create table as` syntax.

Comment: @HoneyBadger OP didn't specify what system they're working with.

Comment: @Outman...tsql is used by other dbms's?

Comment: @HoneyBadger, Sybase?

Comment: Oops, yes, I just saw the obvious outer join issue and responded. The question's a bit unclear about exactly what's required.

Comment: @jarlh, I didn't know that. [Sybase](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00801.1510/html/iqrefso/X315712.htm) doesn't seem to support `create table as` syntax either.

Comment: CTAS is supported by Azure SQL Data Warehouse. Not sure if Microsoft call that dialect TSQL or something else

Answer (score 1):

It could be that what you want is:

```
SELECT a.* 
INTO segments
FROM t_segx a
FULL OUTER JOIN 
SELECT b.*
FROM t.segy b
ON a.c_key = b.c_key
```

which will create the table from the select query.

Or better still

```
SELECT a.* 
INTO segments
FROM t_segx a
FULL OUTER JOIN 
t.segy b
ON a.c_key = b.c_key
```

The `t.sgy` looks odd.

Answer (score 0):

You need to full outer join ON something, you just have another select. Something like:

```
CREATE TABLE segments
WITH(DISTRIBUTION =HASH(customer_key)) AS
SELECT * 
FROM t_segx a
FULL OUTER JOIN t.segy  b
ON a.c_key = b.c_key
```

should work. 
Err, at least as long as those table names are right. I suspect it should be:

```
FULL OUTER JOIN t_segy
```

Or something.

Although as one of the commenters mentioned, if this is TSQL for SQLServer then you need to use select into tablename instead. I think you need a bit more info if you want a working answer.